# Clause starting with "only"

Tags: word-usage

What is the meaning of `only` in this sentence:

> They did not set out to be heroes, only to stay alive; and not all of
> them succeeded.

Does it mean that they did not intend to become heroes, but intended to just stay alive? Or they did not intend to become heores and expected to die, but became heroes, beat the odds and stayed alive?

Comment: _Not all of them succeeded_ seems to imply that some of them did lose their lives.

Answer (score 0):

They intended to stay alive.  It doesn't say what they *expected*.  You can intend to stay alive and expect to die.

Now using general knowledge about people not wanting to die, we can deduce that they made their plan because they expected that it would have the lowest chance of them dying.  Example

> If we stay in the hut the volcano will kill us all.  If we leave, we will probably freeze to death, but we might be able reach safety.  So we will set out.  We expect to die, but we intend to live.

So, without more details we don't know if they expected to die or not. We don't know if they "beat the odds".

Comment: Thanks. The use of "only" can sometime indicate irony. For example 'He tried to avoid smoking, only to get a Cuban cigar gift' . I'm reading this irony in the sentence, or am I wrong for some grammatical reason, rather than unintentional ambiguity of the author?